# Format in R for point prediction of survival analysis

Tags: r, prediction

I am befuddled by the format to perform a simple prediction using R's `survival` package

```
library(survival)
lung.surv <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ 1, data = lung)
```

So fitting a simple exponential regression (for example purposes only) is:

```
lung.reg <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ 1, data = lung, dist="exponential")
```

How would I predict the percent survival at time=400?

When I use the following:

```
myPredict400 <- predict(lung.reg, newdata=data.frame(time=400), type="response")
```

I get the following:

```
myPredict400
       1 
421.7758
```

I was expecting something like 37% so I am missing something pretty obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point with this survival function is to find an empirical distribution that fits the survival times. Essentially you are associating a survival time with a probability. Once you have that distribution, you can pick out the survival rate for a given time.

Try this:

```
library(survival)
lung.reg <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ 1, data = lung)  # because you want a distribution

pct <- 1:99/100  # this creates the empirical survival probabilities
myPredict400 <- predict(lung.reg, newdata=data.frame(time=400),type='quantile', p=pct)

indx = which(abs(myPredict400 - 400) == min(abs(myPredict400 - 400))) # find the closest survival time to 400
print(1 - pct[indx]) # 0.39
```

Straight from the help docs, here's a plot of it:

```
matplot(myPredict400, 1-pct, xlab="Months", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
```

[image]

**Edited**

You're basically fitting a regression to a distribution of probabilities (hence 1...99 out of 100). If you make it go to 100, then the last value of your prediction is `inf` because the survival rate in the 100th percentile is infinite. This is what the `quantile` and `pct` arguments do.

For example, setting `pct = 1:999/1000` you get much more precise values for the prediction (`myPredict400`). Also, if you set `pct` to be some value that's not a proper probability (i.e. less than 0 or more than 1) you'll get an error. I suggest you play with these values and see how they impact your survival rates.

Comment: Hmm.  Typing in "print(1 - pct[indx])" prints out a matrix of NAs.  Did something go wrong here?

Comment: It works but I have another question. I am still new to survival analysis - can you explain in your answer what the myPredict400 is doing?   I don't get how it is using the 98 values in pct (which go from 0.01 to 0.98)